# Why Should I Be "Normal(ized)?"

Tags: sql, etl

I'm creating a log table, and even though I'm a database programmer, and I probably shouldn't want to do this, I'm creating the table such that the initial message inserts a guid and start_time -- all subsequent transactions are updates to other columns which are attributes of the data load: ftp connection, files unzipped...

Why is this a bad idea?  Should I hang my head in shame?  I want a neat, clean table -- one job, one row (I'll build my own  comma delimited list of files that I've processed (or how about a list of ids?  I'll build a list of file ids that joins to a table of files that I've downloaded...  ))

Yes/No?  Go to the back of the bus?

Comment: what has this got to do with etl?

Comment: I think that given the detail in the question there is no definitive answer to this question. I seem to recall a whole module in my university course about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your patterns of insertion and retreival. If you insert all the files into the record in one transaction, and don't need to query individual file names, then you should be fine with the comma separated files. The file name list is then a single item of data, it isn't denormalized.

If you append files to the log record as they are processed, or if you need to query/join individual file names then those are your data elements and you should have a table for them.

In short: it's ok to have a comma separated list, unless you will have to append to it, or split it at some point.

I just covered the file names but the same idea works for other types of data in this scenario.

Comment: Cool -- about to invest some time on this...  Don't want to **undo** it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

One reason why most of the time we are using log **files**, not log **tables** is: we want to know what is happening and how in details and in order. Your single record does **NOT** provide these details...

Comment: Does it make a difference if I mention that the guid joins to an event table (created by SSIS)?

Comment: If you have another table storing individual details than it will help you, but what is the point? You are replacing 1 file with 2 tables?